# Enabling auto layout and size classes for already existing projects does not enable multitasking in iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, ios-autolayout, ios9.1, xcode7.1, split-screen-multitasking

I have existing legacy code which uses .xib files for iPhone and iPad idiom.I want to enable splitview multitasking feature of iPad pro into it.
Since, it has many .xib controllers separated for iPhone and iPad, I am not able to make it adapt multitasking in iPad pro.

I tried:
1) set target to 9.1
2) Requires full screen is no in General tab.
3) iPad version supports all orientations.
4) Using Xcode 7.2

Anybody help would be highly appreciated.